# Unable to connect to Postgresql DB with PHP

Tags: php, postgresql

I am trying to connect to Postgre using a PHP script, but it returns the following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function pg_connect() in C:\wamp\www\contact.php on line 2
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to uncomment this line in php.ini:

```
 extension=php_pgsql.dll
```

Comment: hmm... wamp server doesn't include postgresql installation... do you have postgresql server installed? and also check if you have php_pgsql.dll file in extensions folder

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to have the postgres driver installed into PHP. Find it in your php directory, is named **php_pgsql.dll** and if you have it, check if found in the php ini:

```
;extension=php_pgsql.dll
```

and uncomment it:

```
extension=php_pgsql.dll
```